# The limit of inviting participatants in the event method

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to help using inviting users with next call

```
/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3
```

I suppose I will be inviting all friends of the user.

I however get into trouble that there's a limit on inviting people. Is it possible to know the upper limit of inviting user? In addition, is it a APP limit or PER-USER limit?

Alternatively, are there any JS API/dialog that allows user to invite participants themselves so that we won't hit this limit?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/228861470548080/invited");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlpostf); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, **you can't batch invite at all**:

"people must be prompted to invite specific friends to an event"
https://www.facebook.com/help/www/245886992192344

Technically - before the deletion - you could invite **499** people at the same time in a request.

Otherwise, the Graph will show an error:

*(#105) The number of parameters exceeded the maximum for this operation*

This **PER-REQUEST limit** problem can be solved by cutting your "users" parameter into pieces, and then **sending them in more Graph API calls**.

(Regarding the **PER-APP** and **PER-USER** limit, I don't have any info.)

Practically, **your app will be deleted** without any notifications if you violate the terms.

Comment: What if I get the user's consent beforehand? Like a "select all" button?

Comment: This is exactly why one of my apps got deleted by Facebook. "people must be prompted to invite >>>SPECIFIC<<< friends to an event"

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Glad that I have your advice before my app get banned!

Comment: Glad that your app didn't get banned. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on number of invited users (at least it's not stated in any way on official documentation).

Currently there is no any Dialog or JS-SDK functionality that allow you to invite user's to events, but you can easily instruct users to use "Invite Friends" button at the top of Event's page.

Comment: Actually there is an open bug about Graph API results for attendee list retrieval ([Graph API event attendee list limited to ~999 users](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293819407299977)) but this seems unrelated to the question

Comment: Basically, what I am attempting to do is list all IDs of user's friend then invite them to a particular event. Here's what returned FYI:
{"message":"(#105) The number of parameters exceeded the maximum for this operation","type":"OAuthException","code":105}}

PS: Can't tag your name :/

Comment: @IsaacLongKwan, are you trying to issue `GET` or `POST` request? Probably `POST` is better than dealing with big number of users. (BTW, Owner of post will be always notified about response, so no need to tag in that case ;))

Comment: I just feel that you might be coming back to this thread:P So anyway, yes, I am sending a HTTP POST request. Please see the updated thread above to see my code.